# extract content from a jquery object

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to clean facebook cache for my site, i can't do it manually because it has thousands of url...

in order to clear cache, i created a list containing li a elements,all having a clickable link

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var links = $("ul li a");

links.each( function( index, element ){
//alert(element);

//var res = element.replace("http://www.saludymedicinas.com.mx/process/","");
window.open('https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=' +element)
});

});
```

res is saving http://www.saludymedicinas.com.mx/test/http://www.saludymedicinas.com.mx/folder/etc.html
i wanted to get rid of everything before test/ so facebook is not recognizing that url

i just wanted res=http://www.saludymedicinas.com.mx/folder/etc.html

help please,

Comment: so what is the problem , replace doesnt work ?

Comment: i tried

    element.replace('a','b')

but it says Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'replace'

Comment: so you actually used element not str , correct ?

Comment: because you should use element.attr("href")

Comment: if you can upload full code then it is better.

Comment: here is the working link http://www.saludymedicinas.com.mx/test.html try clicking some url, and when u get to facebook debug, the url is wrong because bad url is formed XD, wnat to get rid of first http part

Comment: i tried element.attr too, but it say that object error thing :s

thats all code inside my .js file, in html file is containing 3/xxxx links so i just put 3 XD

Comment: what do you want the link url to be like ?

Comment: should be like https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.saludymedicinas.com.mx%2Fcentros-de-salud%2Facidez-estomacal%2Farticulos-relacionados%2Fcruda.html

is there any other method? like setInterval?

Comment: mhmhmh, i think i can't do that, autoclicking links in order to clear facebook cache, even if get the correct link.... like before url, the url is correct but facebook is not srapping that

Comment: btw, when i hover over my links, i get the wrong url(process/ should not be there), but inside the code is fine(without process/), hows that possible?